# c++ error C2039 only on release

Tags: c++, visual-studio

we have to following file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Dice.h"


void Dice::Init(const unsigned seed) {

    std::cout << "Dice is initialized" << std::endl;
    _randomEngine = std::mt19937(seed);
    _standardChance = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(1, 20);
}

Dice::Dice(unsigned int seed) {
    if (seed == 0) {
        std::random_device rd;
        seed = rd();
        std::cout << "seed is " << seed << std::endl;
    }
    Init(seed);
}

Dice::~Dice()
{
}

int Dice::GetChanceCalculation() {
    return _standardChance(_randomEngine);
}
int Dice::GetOtherRandomNumber(const int minimum, const int maximum) {
    const std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(minimum, maximum);
    return dist(_randomEngine);
}

int Dice::GetOtherRandomNumber(const int maximum) {
    return GetOtherRandomNumber(0, maximum);
}

std::mt19937 Dice::GetRandomEngine() const
{
    return _randomEngine;
}
```

it works fine in debugging mode but when i build for release i get the following errors:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\random(2500): error C2039: '_Debug_message': is not a member of 'std'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\random(30): note: see declaration of 'std'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\random(2500): error C3861: '_Debug_message': identifier not found
```

Some said that it could be the std::cout or the order of includes but none of these works.
Does anyone have a solution?(building on x86 if anyone wonders)

Comment: Post how the IDE invokes the compiler for this individual compilation unit for each of your two configurations.

Comment: When you created the project, how did you do that? Have you changed any project settings?

Comment: If `<random>` is precompiled, it might run the risk of not being recompiled for release. I don't know whether that's the case or if VS is smarter about that.

Comment: Check your include directories in project properties. They are not necessarily copied over from debug to release build.

Comment: The first thing to do is remove `#include  "stdafx.h". That's a Microsoft "optimization" that sometimes creates problems.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE]. You are not showing stdafx.h and Dice.h, so we cannot reproduce the problem with the input you gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for answering this so late but the problem apparently was a combination of wrong includes in the stdafx.h and some wrong settings for linker on release.
I want to thank everyone for taking their time to look at my problem.